# How to display search engine results like JSON file using HTTP client?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, httpclient

Convert google search engine result like JSON file using method get of HTTP client
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H82A8.png)

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
this._http.get(`https://www.google.com/gen_204?s=web&t=aft&atyp=csi&ei=6MeQXbuYCcrBkwWCw6jgCQ&rt=wsrt
.358,aft.450,prt.424,sct.377&bl=tf62&ima=1&imad=0&imn=5.json`)
.subscribe(posts => console.log(posts));
}
```

I tried to use .json or =json for display like JSON file but display error message: 
**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: You might want to look up "CORS".

Comment: But doesn't the best solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. The issue is that you're trying to make a cross-domain request to an endpoint that doesn't allow cross-domain requests. You could do it on the server side, or do it however Google allows you to make such a request.